# CSocket - DataArrival Not Occurring (GET Request)

Tags: http, vb6, get, winsock, webrequest

I'm attempting to do a GET request in VB6 using CSocket. The data is sent successfully however no response is received (tested on multiple sites). My code is below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents WinSock As CSocket

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set WinSock = New CSocket
End Sub

Private Sub btnConnect_Click()
WinSock.Protocol = sckTCPProtocol
WinSock.Connect "winhome.de", 80

MsgBox "Connecting..."
End Sub

Private Sub WinSock_OnConnect()
MsgBox "Connected."

Dim Data$
Data = "GET http://www.winhome.de/index.html HTTP/1.0" & vbCrLf & "Accept: */*" & _
vbCrLf & "Accept: text/html" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

WinSock.SendData Data
MsgBox Data
End Sub

Private Sub WinSock_OnDataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
Dim Data$
WinSock.GetData Data, vbString
MsgBox Data
End Sub
```

The OnConnect event never seems to trigger, but works fine with a normal WinSock control, Any help?

Answer (score 0):

For these scenarios you don't want any "blocking" debugging, including `MsgBox` or IDE breaks -- the events get lost.

E.g. accumulate your debug logs into a string or a file and look at the results after a run.